# Send email to multiple recipients with different content

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I'm trying to send mails to multiple recipients with JavaMail. The content of each message is to be different. The program sends me an e-mail to different recipients but with the same content. Can any one help me. Her is my source code.

```
public static void postMail(String[] recipients, String subject, Timestamp time)throws MessagingException {
 String nachricht = null;
 String link = null;
 Session session = MailUtil.getGMailSession("username", "password");
 Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

 msg.setSubject(subject);


for(int i=0; i<=recipients.length-1;i++){
 System.out.println(recipients[i]);
 link = recipients[i] + "/" + time; 
 msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients[i]));
}//endOf forSchleife
message = link
msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
Transport.send(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think that the code should be like below:

    for(int i=0; i<=recipients.length-1;i++){
         Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
         msg.setSubject(subject);
         System.out.println(recipients[i]);
         link = recipients[i] + "/" + time; 
         //msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients[i]));
         //Try this please            
         msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients[i]));

message = link
        msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
        Transport.send(msg);
    }//endOf forSchleife
inside of the for loop...
```

Comment: When I write this into the for loop, I get the same problem as before. One mail to every recipient with the same content. But Each recipient should get its own link from the email address and timestamp

Comment: You should also place Transport.send(msg); in the for loop. What you are doing here is sending one e-mail to multiple recepients with the message for the last recepient. Is's impossible to send e-mail to multiple recepients with different messages at once. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: When I place Transport.send(msg) in the for loop, then send the programm me to any recepient three mails. That is not right. Can you help me.

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you check it wether it works or not? In my opinion it should be ok now. Please also take a look at the following documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#setRecipient%28javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,%20javax.mail.Address%29. It says that: setRecipient - Set the recipient address. All addresses of the specified type are replaced by the address parameter; addRecipient - Add these recipient addresses to the existing ones of the given type.